# read-only file system on emulator

Tags: file-system, android-emulator

I need to change `/system/etc/hosts` file on my emulator, and no matter what I do, I get "read-only file system" error. Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried editing the file manually as `su` in `adb shell`, I tried pushing the file in device monitor (in Android studio), also tried `adb remount` to remount the file system as many online resources suggest.

Thanks!
Konstantin

Comment: Have you tried (as root): `mount -o remount,rw /system` and then editing the hosts file?

Comment: Maybe ADB isn't running as root ... Try `adb kill-server` and then `adb root`

Answer (score 3):

I tried your answer but it didn't work.

Eventually the following [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117715/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-android-studio-emulator-running-in-nougat#47622017) worked.

> ```
> 1) android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator -avd <avdname> -writable-system
> 2) ./adb root
> 3) ./adb remount
> 4) ./adb push <local>/hosts /etc/hosts
> ```
>
> Android file host can be
>
> ```
> /etc/hosts <--- This worked for me
> /etc/system/hosts
> /system/etc/hosts
> ```
>
> Check
>
> ```
> 1) ./adb shell
> 2) cat /etc/hosts
> 3) ping customsite.com
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I found this question Googling for the same issue. I solved with these steps:

(for italian-speaking people: see my full writeup [Guida definitiva: come modificare il file hosts di Android tramite PC (senza errori adb: error: failed to copy 'hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': couldn't create file: Read-only file system oppure Permission denied)](https://turbolab.it/pc-642/guida-come-modificare-file-hosts-android-senza-errori-couldn-t-create-file-read-only-file-system-permission-denied-1130)

### Mount FS as RW

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

( [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794659/how-to-change-the-hosts-file-on-android#comment31429467_8749733) )

### Run ADB as root

```
adb root
```

credit: @Noob Food

### Push again

```
adb push hosts /system/etc/hosts
```